# Reverse Split_part SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to there a way to delimit data and select the 2nd to last substring

**Sample Input:**

```
*------------------------------------*
|       Name                         |
*------------------------------------*
|Mike__NYC_180x9_School              |
|Oak_Ann_1_LA_1x190_Uni              | 
|Tiger_King_Al_car_12_10x15_sample   |
*------------------------------------*
```

Desired Output:

```
*--------------*
|Account number|
*--------------*
|180x9         |
|1x190         | 
|10x15         |
*--------------*
```

Answer (score 3):

reverse the string then take the second word and then reverse it again.

```
select reverse(split_part(reverse(Name),'_',2));
```